# Cppcheck Cmake integration: abort build on warning

Tags: c++, cmake, cppcheck

I just started using `cppcheck` in a `C++` project and learned that it can be integrated into `cmake`.
In my `cmake` project, I integrated it into the `CMakeLists.txt` file  via

```
find_program(CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK NAMES cppcheck)
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find the program cppcheck.")
endif()
list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK "--enable=all" )
```

Now, during the compilation process, `cppcheck` runs fine. I have set `-WError` for all my compiler warnings, is there a way to do the same for `cppcheck`, i.e. make the build fail in case a `cppcheck` warning is thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a make program calls programs like the compiler, linker or whatever other tool like cppcheck in your case, then the return value of the program is evaluated. If any program returns the value `0`, then this is considered as successful by `make` so that it continues. If any program returns another value then `0`, then `make` fails and does not continue. That is a well-known convention. So all you have to do is to configure `cppcheck` in a way that it returns `0` in case of success and another value in case of failure. You can achieve that with the parameter `--error-exitcode=1`:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK "--enable=all" "--error-exitcode=10")
```

From cppcheck documentation:

> ```
> --error-exitcode=<n> If errors are found, integer [n] is returned instead of
>                      the default '0'. '1' is returned
>                      if arguments are not valid or if no input files are
>                      provided. Note that your operating system can modify
>                      this value, e.g. '256' can become '0'.
> ```

However, this will also fail, if there is any message of cppcheck. You probably need to adjust the `enable` switch to severity classes which are of interest for you. Alternatively, you can suppress messages, please see cppcheck command line documentation how to achieve that.